# Office365-REST-Python-Client Multifactor Authentication

Tags: python, authentication, oop, office365, sharepoint-online

## Goal

I would like to access Sharepoint files within my company and use it as a kind of SFTP but with regrads to the current Authentication restrictions. To sum up I would like to distribute and download the newest (processed) files in any Sharepoint folder.

## Background info for Problem

Due to company restrictions it is not possible to install Python on every PC, thats why I am searching for other options to create value with my developments. We also had a class that was able to do so in the past.
To achieve that we where using Office365-REST-Python-Client and user credentials.

## Current Status

Since a couple of month we are not able to access Sharepoint via REST and Python. The company implemented Multifactor Authentication, so once every X days we need to update our Access via the mobile phone where we get displayed something from the app and need to insert that in the Authenticator on the mobilephone.

## My IDEA

My Idea is to save the token that gets generated from the App and load the token whenever I use my self developed Sharepoint class that is based on Office365-REST-Python-Client. However I am not able to post a request to the Sharepoint via Rest so I could enter anything in the mobilephone and retrieve the token so I can save it.

## Question

1. Can i create a POST or any other request so my Phone will display that i need to insert something?
2. Is it possible to retrieve a token based on usercredentials without any admin rights and with regard to the question above?

## How we did it before

```py
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.folders.folder import Folder
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

from HELPER import Helper # own created class

import tempfile

class MySharePoint(Helper):
    '''
    This class is the base class for all SharePoint related classes. It contains all the methods that are used by the other classes. 
    One can download, upload and get inormation about files and folders. provide the credentials in the .env file and teh access is granted to the SharePoint site.
    The Sharepoint site name and the document root folder can be changed in the class variables.
    '''
    SHAREPOINT_DOC_ROOT = 'Docs' # The Folder where the files are stored
    SHAREPOINT_SITE = 'TeamSite' # The SharePoint site name comes right after the sites/ in the URL
    def __init__(self, username:Optional[str] = '', password:Optional[str] = '', company_site: Optional[str] = '') -> None:
        self.client_context = {'company_site':company_site, 'username':username, 'password':self.encode_password(password)}
        self.root_folder = None
        self.tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=os.path.join('data'), prefix='temp_')
    ...
    @property
    def client_context(self) -> ClientContext:
        return self._client_context
    
    @client_context.setter
    def client_context(self, kwargs:dict) -> None:
        """ This method sets the client context of the SharePoint site. It is used in the other methods to get the files and folders.

        Args:
            kwargs (dict): A dictionary with the following keys: company_site, username, password

        Raises:
            e: An exception that is raised if the authentication fails.
        """        
        try:
            ctx_authorization = AuthenticationContext( os.getenv("SHAREPOINT_SITE", kwargs['company_site']))
            ctx_authorization.acquire_token_for_user( os.getenv("SHAREPOINT_USER", kwargs['username']), os.getenv("SHAREPOINT_PW", self.decode_password(kwargs['password'])))
            
            self._client_context =  ClientContext(os.getenv("SHAREPOINT_SITE", kwargs['company_site']), ctx_authorization)
            logging.info(f"\nSharePoint authentication successful.")
            
        except (ValueError)  as e:
            logging.critical(f"\nSharePoint authentication failed. The following exception has occured:\n{e}\n")
            raise e

>>> # OUTPUT
>>> Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access ''
```

Everything I tried is very connected to the implemented SharepointClass I also did try to create A client id and secret but since I do not have any Admin right to do so it was not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution would indeed be to use a Client ID / Client Certificate (or Secret), but your company needs to give you two things:

- Admin rights on your site collection
- Enabling the legacy Add-In right management for site administrators (which was disabled by default since summer)

Outside of this solution, there should be not way to circumvent the MFA configuration, as it is intended to prevent you from doing just what you're trying to do.

I would advise to review the way files move in your projects/company as normally, people would create Teams, share OneDrive Files, create full SharePoint sites and simply synchronize them on their respective computer using OneDrive, thus rendering the push/pull process automatic and seemless.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
Could you please clarify what you mean by **site-collection**?
- The one teams site I use to upload folder? 
- How would it than look like if this class would be used for various projects and teams within the company?  
2. The whole company site? 

3. Do you maybe have a link to the Add-In right enablement so I can get more information about it and get back to the team responsible for microsoft in my company?